# How to set data table two data column as datasource in asp.net dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dropdown, aspx-user-control

[image]I have a `DataTable` called cachedData.
It values like this
| COL1 | COL2 |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 12    |- |
| -| 59|
| 32    |- |
| -| 63|

I want to set these values to a dropdown without considering these as two columns.

Ex : dropdown values should be 12,59,32,63

I tried but this gives me an error.Please help me to bind this `dataTable` values to dropdown

```
            if (cachedData != null)
            {

                this.DigitalChannelSignatureDropDownList.DataTextField = "COL1"+"COL2";
                this.DigitalChannelSignatureDropDownList.DataValueField = "COL1"+"COL2";
                this.DigitalChannelSignatureDropDownList.DataSource = cachedData;
                this.DigitalChannelSignatureDropDownList.DataBind();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not clear what the "-" values are in your table?

However, you could use a union query, and say this:

```
 SELECT COL1 AS MyCol FROM MyTable WHERE COL1 <> '-'
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT COL2 AS MyCol FROM MyTable WHERE COL2 <> '-'
```

The output of above then becomes this:

```
  MyCol
  -----
  12        
  32        
  59        
  63
```

And perhaps your '-' was for null values, so change the above SQL to:

```
 SELECT COL1 AS MyCol FROM MyTable WHERE COL1 is not null
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT COL2 AS MyCol FROM MyTable WHERE COL2 is not null
```

So, now to load up the drop-down list, we have this:

Markup:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">

        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And code behind is thus this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string strSQL =
                @"SELECT COL1 AS MyCol FROM MyTable WHERE COL1 <> '-'
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT COL2 AS MyCol FROM MyTable WHERE COL2 <> '-'";

            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "MyCol";
            DropDownList1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,"Please Select"); // optional 

        }
    }
```

And of course, code to return a datatable from the SQL can be this:

```
    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```